# Can't figure out what is wrong with my binary addition algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, binary

I'm creating a binary addition algorithm in python. from the output I'm getting it seems as though the binary strings are getting inverted and added that way. I can't seem to figure out what's causing this.

```
def addBinary(x, y):
    carry = False
    result = ''   
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if carry == True:
            if x[i] == '1' and y[i] == '1':
                result = '1' + result
            if x[i] =='1' and y[i] == '0':
                result = '0' + result
            if x[i] =='0' and y[i] == '1':
                result = '0' + result
            if x[i] == '0' and y[i] == '0':
                result = '1' + result
                carry = False
        else:
            if x[i] == '1' and y[i] == '1':
                result = '0' + result
                carry = True
            if x[i] =='1' and y[i] == '0':
                result = '1' + result
            if x[i] =='0' and y[i] == '1':
                result = '1' + result
            if x[i] == '0' and y[i] == '0':
                result = '0' + result
        print(result)
    if carry == True:
        result = '1' + result
    else:
        result = '0' + result
    return result
print(addBinary('10110101','10010001'))
```

and the output is

```
0
10
110
0110
10110
110110
0110110
00110110
000110110
```

the correct output is 0101000110

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing your math in the wrong direction. Your code starts at the most significant place value, and works backwards.

Ie Your example is actually doing 10101101 + 10001001.

Change your for loop to: `for i in range(len(x) - 1, -1, -1):` OR reverse your inputs with `x = x[::-1]` and `y = y[::-1]`.

Also your last if statement should be `if carry:` since it's either true or false, not 1 or 0.

Comment: wow! that was obvious, Thank you this worked.